# Is it possible to package installed software?

Tags: package-management, deb

I was wondering if it is possible to make a package of installed software? I want to use modified software from my current installation on another one, so if possible, packaging it to install it on my other system seems to be the easiest way. Or do you guys have other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "modified software from my current installation"? You modified source code and compiled it?

Comment: I modified source code of programs that I already have installed on my system. But I don't know if I can make a package (for example .deb) of it to use the same program with the modification on my other system. I just edited it at the moment.

Comment: If it was just for the files, you can make an installer of any list of files, to be placed on specific locations. The trick is that you don't know what pre/post install scripts might be needed, links might be created, and what more the "real" installer changed to your system. Also you'd need to take care of dependecies. Could you give an example?

Comment: You cannot modify source code of installed programs not recompiling them. Do you talk about modification of configuration files?

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm not describing it right. What I mean is that I changed things in the `/usr/bin` and `.desktop` files. I want to use those files for other installations and I don't know if just copying and replacing it is the best way to do it (like, would I break the application?).

Comment: If it is just minor modifications to one or two files, I'd suggest just copy those files after having installed the programs If it is for personal use. You can even make a small script if you'd like to do it repeatedly. Btw, is it for personal use?

Comment: This helped me to make a .deb file of the edited program: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717

Comment: I know the post, one of my favorites. It helped me make my very first installer as well :)

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to put it in a PPA, and it'll work just fine :P

Comment: Maud, the `.deb` installer created like that won't "survive" Linian, it is just to get the principle.

Comment: Maud, to create a fit answer, it is necessary to know what your intentions are. You mention a ppa, but that kind of clashes with the idea of "personal" use, and a `.deb` file seems quite overdone for just one or two files to replace.  Also you mention you made some changes to files in `/usr/bin`, but I can hardly believe you are editing files in there, not really the "tweak" section of your desktop. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit tired when I wrote that :P I meant `/usr/share/*application*`. I want to pack the application with the changes I made and some additional scripts. If I put them in my **Personal** Package Archive, I can make the changes, make a package and upload it. I made a test package following the steps in the tutorial and it worked (installed without errors using GDebi installer).  I might just write a bashscript that I can download from my systems with some commands that download the edited files and put them in place. That might be easier than making packages.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to move the modified source to your other system and compile it there.

But you also can create a deb package too.

[Here is one of the guides](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html).

But it will need some effort to learn doing it right.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Do you really think that it is good to copy here the whole guide? Everything is essential there.

Comment: could you summarise it using the headings, i.e you need to Check the Program etc. Just an outline? I upvoted because I think it;s a good answer - even without an edit.

Comment: I downvoted this because I really think "yes you can, it will take some effort to learn..." is good enough to call it an answer.

Comment: LOL. But it is the only  frank answer that can be given to such a question. A step-by-step guide for packaging does not exist. And main idea was that it is not worth learning all that, if one or two modified programs are needed to be moved. But it is an option too.

Comment: This guide is about downloading the package, editing it and recompiling it ,right? My question is more if I can "copy" or pack the files that are already on my system. I found this site: http://pkgs.org/. It tells the location where files off the package are installed. So I was wondering if I could use that information to my effort.

Comment: You did not give any details on what "files" are you talking about. Maybe it makes sense to explain what kind of software you modified and installed. Then a better answer could be given.